# How to send a new build to a repo using git hub actions?

Tags: continuous-integration, appium, circleci, github-actions

This is a bit unconventional but I am trying to set an automated testing suite that involves 3 repos; the iOS/android app repos and another for our python tests which use appium. Everything works manually but now we would like to set it up with github actions or circleci.

This is the ideal workflow I have in my mind; our frontend developer creates a new release on GH, that sends a trigger which creates a new app build and then triggers the test repo which will run the tests on that new build.

I've been able to set up workflows where one repos actions triggers something on a different repo with GHA repo dispatch, but what i'm unable to figure out is getting the new build from one repo to another. Is it even possible? If it's not, is there a way to get that new app build into my test repo another way?

Im a junior dev and this is my first attempt at setting up continuous integration so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To let your test repository know what it should be testing you can send it the git commit SHA of the release when you trigger a `repository_dispatch`.

```
      - name: Repository Dispatch
        uses: peter-evans/repository-dispatch@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          repository: org/test-repo
          event-type: my-event
          client-payload: '{"sha": "${{ github.sha }}"}'
```

Then you can checkout that SHA in the test repository workflow and test it.

```
name: Repository Dispatch
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [my-event]
jobs:
  myEvent:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          repository: org/build-repo
          ref: ${{ github.event.client_payload.sha }}
```

Note that in both workflows you need to use a `repo` scoped [PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token).

In general, it is best to test build artifacts before they are released. So you might want to think about redesigning slightly to run your tests earlier in the pipeline. Perhaps on push to master, or testing pull request branches before they merge to master, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing it works similarly on a PR, push to master etc?